# Удаление пробелов в колонке

Tags: запрос, база-данных, mysql

Пытаюсь удалить пробелы слева в колонке `title`.

```
update books set title=ltrim(title) WHERE title!=ltrim(title)
```

Запрос очень долго висит и висит.

Наверное, что-то делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для теста создай временную таблицу, где будет 10 записей и проверь работу запроса.

Comment: Сделал тестовую таблицу, с 8000+ записей, столбик varchar. Запрос выполнился за 0.085 с. =)
а на рабочей таблице (столбик varchar 255, около 1000 записей) подвисает и всё. чудеса))

Comment: Вобщем запрос зависает, но на самом деле все что нужно обрезает. А на другом сервере(рабочем) запустился на ура и все ок. Можно сказать что проблема решена

Answer (score 3):

Зачем вообще `WHERE`? Сделайте сразу

```
UPDATE `books` SET `title`=ltrim(title)
```

Comment: всё правильно, mysql не будет затрагивать те записи где нет пробелов слева.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, запрос делает вовсе не то, что нужно. Конкретно про MySQL не скажу, но, вообще говоря, оператор неравенства в SQL пишется как "<>".

Comment: дело не в блоке WHERE, я сначала без него писал. тоже самое было((

Comment: а вобще вот тут написано что <> и != тоже самое
http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Comparison_Operators.html

Comment: но это mysql, возможно в других субд != не используется..

Answer (score 0):

Where можно убрать, без него будет быстрее
Какое количество записей в таблице?
Какая нагрузка на базу?
Какой тип поля title?

Comment: На 10 записях удаление where не показало разницу. Может нагрузка на базу большая или кол-во записей очень велико?